# JavaFX 2 mediaplayer - seek function is inaccurate or does not work at all

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, mp3

I am creating a music player with JavaFX8 and Java 8, and I ran into a problem, similar to what others have mentioned before. I want to create a slider which represents the timeline of the song. The user can drag the slider around to change the current playback time of the song. The slider has as much ticks as the audio file has seconds.

I am currently supporting .m4a and .mp3 files.

Depending on the file format, the seek function is either slightly inaccurate, extremely inaccurate or works fine. (see below for detailed information)

I already moved the seek function into the main JavaFX thread, as someone suggested on another question. Did not change anything.

I tried to ignore the slider, and simply use the seek function if the mediaplayer reached a certain time stamp. E.g. when the mediaplayer exceeds second 10, I called mediaplayer.seek(Duration.toSeconds(25)).

The function in the main JavaFX Thread, which should jump to the time stamp corresponding to the slider value (which is draggable).

```
public void seekToSecond(){
         currentSongmediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(uiController.getSliderValue()));
}
```

This is the code, that updates the slider position, according to the current timestamp the mediaplayer currently is. It runs in a JavaFX background service as long as the status of the mediaplayer is equal to "Playing".
But it should not have any effect on the playback time of the audio file.

```
if(uiController.getDragged()) {
  uiController.setTimeLineDraggedFalse();
}
uiController.setSliderPosition((int)currentSongmediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds());

sleep(100);   //sleep for 1/10 of a second
```

When I use the mediaplayer.seek(double time) function, four different outcomes can occur: 
If the files is a .mp3 file:

1) the new playback point in the song is e.g. 0:24s, but the mediaplayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds function gives me e.g 0:26s as current time. The 0:26s would have be the correct value, as this is also the value I wanted to jump to. So at the end of the song, the getCurrentTime() function returns time stamps, which are higher than the mediaplayer.getDuration() value.

2) Same situation as in 1) but this time the playback point is always 0:00s instead of 0:24s, as long as do not jump over ~50% of the song. If I jump over this mark, then it is some random point that is still off by a lot of seconds.

3) In a few cases it works

If it is a .m4a file:

1) It works fine, just as expected

At this point I am completely clueless, and do not see what could be wrong, except that somehow the seek function has a bug or somehow most of my mp3 files do not work.

here is a minimal code example:

For the path, simply put a mp3 file and replace the duration of in seek with something really close to the end of the song, so that it is manually detectable, that the song plays longer than it should. (e.g. 1s)

The main class:

```
package sample;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    static MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        MediaView mv = new MediaView();
        File file = new File("path/to/file.mp3");
        Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mv);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        player.seek(Duration.seconds(40));
        player.play();
    }

    public static void seekTest(){
        System.out.println("hi");
        player.seek(Duration.seconds(/*time where it is manually detectable, that the second is not correct (e.g. 1s before end of song)*/));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The fxml controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {


   @FXML
   public void buttonPressed(){
      Main.seekTest();
   }

}
```

My fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="-7.0" layoutY="-7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="85.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Group>
```

Hope someone can help me,

best regards,
Luca

Comment: What happens when you try a more recent version of JavaFX such as 8, 11, or 12? Also, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I added the code, and I have to apologize. Of course it is JavaFX 8, not JavaFX 2. I misread that in IntelliJ, because it shows JavaFX2 regardless of the JDK I'm using. I already wanted to move to JavaFX 11, but that does not work out, as somehow I cannot register media views. I read about this issue online as well, and tehy said, that somehow it is not included in these versions.